# File path in production mode

Tags: electron, electron-builder, electron-packager

Developing an app in electron, everything is working fine with file path in development mode. I created the "documents" folder,  in which documents will be stored.

```
 var dir = path.join(__dirname, 'documents'); 
 fs.readdir(dir, function (err, files) {
  if (err) {
    console.log('Unable to scan directory: ' + err);
  } 

  var files_with_dirs = files.map(function(name) {
    return (dir + '/'+ name);
  });
```

This code return all files in "documents" folder.

[image]

But in production mode when i pack my app, a folder with many files is created, the path becomes like this.

[image]

How to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

For paths pointing to internal resources, I'd suggest using a relative path and building it on the fly

```
var p = upath.toUnix(upath.join(__dirname, "documents", "this-image.jpg));
```

Where [__dirname](https://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/modules.html#modules_dirname) is the path to the currently executing file.

I use the [upath](https://www.npmjs.com/package/upath) `toUnix` function because it normalizes the path to use forward slashes – which has worked better for me with cross--platform apps..

Comment: Why not just use [`path.normalize(...)`](https://nodejs.org/api/path.html#path_path_normalize_path) - more general that way

Comment: @pushkin - I needed a format that was consistent so that app-generated files could be shared cross-platform.